# Calculation of Fixed point set

Tags: algebraic-topology, finite-groups

Let $p,q$ be two distinct primes and let $G_p$  and $G_q$ be nontrivial $p$-group and $q$-group respectively. Let $G = G_p \rtimes G_q$. Embed $G_q \subset U(n_1), G \subset U(n) $  where $U(n_1), U(n)$ are any compact connected Lie groups.Consider $W = U(n_1) \ast (U(n)/G_q)$ ,where $\ast$ is topological join operation.

Question : Why $W^{G_p}= \{  x \in W : g.x = x  \; \forall g \in G_p\} = U(n_1)?$